# Feeding parameters into placeholders in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get into tensorflow, setting up a network and then feeding data to it. For some reason I end up with the error message `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. I made a minimal example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
K = 10

lchild = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(K))
rchild = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(K))
parent = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(lchild, rchild))

input = [ tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([K])),
          tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([K])) ]

with tf.Session() as sess :
    print(sess.run([parent], feed_dict={ lchild: input[0], rchild: input[1] }))
```

Basically, I'm setting up a network with place holders and a sequence of input embeddings that I want to learn, and then I try to run the network, feeding the input embeddings into it. From what I can tell by searching for the error message, there might be something wrong with my `feed_dict`, but I can't see any obvious mismatches in eg. dimensionality.

So, what did I miss, or how did I get this completely backwards?

EDIT: I've edited the above to clarify that the input represents embeddings that need to be learned. I guess the question can be asked more sharply as: *Is it possible to use placeholders for parameters?*

Comment: The error I see for a similar attempt: "TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inputs should be numpy arrays.

So, instead of `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([K]))`, simply write `np.random.randn(K)` and everything should work as expected.

EDIT (The question was clarified after my answer):

It is possible to use placeholders as parameters but in a slightly different way. For example:

```
lchild = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(K))
rchild = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(K))
parent = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(lchild, rchild))
loss = <some loss that depends on the parent tensor or lchild/rchild>
# Compute gradients with respect to the input variables
grads = tf.gradients(loss, [lchild, rchild])

inputs = [np.random.randn(K), np.random.randn(K)]
for i in range(<number of iterations>):
    np_grads = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={lchild:inputs[0], rchild:inputs[1])
    inputs[0] -= 0.1 * np_grads[0]
    inputs[1] -= 0.1 * np_grads[1]
```

It is not however the best or easiest way to do this. The main problem with it is that at every iteration you need to copy numpy arrays in and out of the session (which is running potentially on a different device like GPU).

Placeholders generally are used to feed the data external to the model (like texts or images). The way to solve it using tensorflow utilities would be something like:

```
lchild = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([K])
rchild = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([K])
parent = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(lchild, rchild))
loss = <some loss that depends on the parent tensor or lchild/rchild>
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(loss).minimize(0.1)

for i in range(<number of iterations>):
    sess.run(train_op)

# Retrieve the weights back to numpy:
np_lchild = sess.run(lchild)
```

Comment: But will they still be in the compute graph so that I can get gradients for them if I don't wrap them in something from tensorflow?

Comment: Well, gradients with respect to random values/constants should be 0 so it doesn't matter from the gradients perspective whether the noise is coming from the tensorflow or numpy.

I think I misunderstood your post. You need to specify which variables you want to be learnable and initialize them with random values but then you also need to create some kind of loss function that would tell the optimizer how far we are from the optimal result.

The input nodes are typically not learnable and the loss depends on both the inputs and the variables (parameters) of your graph.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not making my minimalized example clear enough on that point. Yes, the input variables need to be learned (which is why I used tf.Variable for them). So it's not possible to use placeholders for parameters that need to be learned?

Comment: That's correct. Placeholders are used to define information that comes from outside the model (like batches of text or images). You don't have to use feed_dict if you don't have any such data to be given to the model.

In your case, you can simply write:
```parent = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(input[0], input[1]))```

Comment: Problem for me is that it scales poorly... anyway, thanks for clearing that up for me. Can you update your answer to reflect the discussion so I can accept it with the clear conscience that anyone else wandering into the same mess can find out fast (without wading through this discussion thread). :-) Cheers!